# Neos: Nodes from deactivated/deleted Package still there

Tags: typo3, neoscms

I've been playing around with Typo3 Neos. So I've installed it according to [this](http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/GettingStarted/Installation.html) tutorial, except i didnt import the demo Package.

Just to be safe, I deactivated and deleted the TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org package, before flushing the cache. So when i log into the backend, there is the "print" button, in the preview part of the menu, and there are custom nodes which are defined in the demo package (which i deactivated and deleted). It isnt hard to imagine, when i try to add these Nodes i receive an error message:

```
Failed to render element
    page<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/
    body<TYPO3.TypoScript:Template>/
    content/
    main<TYPO3.Neos:PrimaryContent>/
    default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
    element<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection>/
    itemRenderer<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCase>/
    default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
    element<TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:Carousel>
Invalid resource URI "resource://TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org/Private/Templates/NodeTypes/Carousel.html": Package "TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org" is not available. (201402131504259fdc08)
```

It clearly says there is no Carousel Node (because the package where the carousel should be, was deleted). So here is my Question: Why is this still there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you flushed the Cache correctly. In Production context it is

```
FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:flush --force
```

But it seems more likely that in your TYPO3 Content Repository, you still have a Carousel content which of course isn't deleted on installing the Demo Package. So have a look at your Node table and check for the node type `TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:Carousel` and delete these nodes.